# Not able to compare two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, types

I have two Dataframes, df1 and df2 with same structure.
I want to find common rows between them using `df1.merge(df2)` but there is one row I am facing issue with:

```
>>> df2
  reference_period analyzed_domain account is_misc total_estimated_visits  total_estimated_monthly_unique_visitors  total_estimated_visit_duration  total_estimated_pageviews  estimated_deduplicated_audience
0       2017-11-01          abc     xyz       0                   1000                                    278.0                          5788.0                    80159.0                              0.0
>>> df1=df1.head(1)
>>> df1
  reference_period analyzed_domain account is_misc total_estimated_visits  total_estimated_monthly_unique_visitors  total_estimated_visit_duration  total_estimated_pageviews  estimated_deduplicated_audience
0       2017-11-01          abc     xyz       0                   1000                                    278.0                          5788.0                    80159.0                              0.0
>>> df1==df2
   reference_period  analyzed_domain  account  is_misc  total_estimated_visits  total_estimated_monthly_unique_visitors  total_estimated_visit_duration  total_estimated_pageviews  estimated_deduplicated_audience
0              True             True     True    False                    True                                     True                            True                       True                             True
>>> df1.dtypes
reference_period                           datetime64[ns]
analyzed_domain                                    object
account                                            object
is_misc                                            object
total_estimated_visits                             object
total_estimated_monthly_unique_visitors           float64
total_estimated_visit_duration                    float64
total_estimated_pageviews                         float64
estimated_deduplicated_audience                   float64
dtype: object
>>> df2.dtypes
reference_period                           datetime64[ns]
analyzed_domain                                    object
account                                            object
is_misc                                            object
total_estimated_visits                             object
total_estimated_monthly_unique_visitors           float64
total_estimated_visit_duration                    float64
total_estimated_pageviews                         float64
estimated_deduplicated_audience                   float64
dtype: object
```

I am not sure why python is not able to equate is_misc column.
Could someone please help?
Thanks

Comment: try converting the integers into floats

Comment: "I am not sure why python is not able to equate is_misc column." What do you mean when you say that it isn't? Are you talking about what happened when you tried `df1.merge(df2)`? You should *show exactly what happened when you tried that*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas dtype object is either str or mixed. So it can be either text or mixed numeric and non-numeric values. In either `df1`or `df2`, the `0` value for the `is_misc` column is most likely string type, so you can convert both of them to either string or int, and then run the comparison again, which will then equal `True`. try this:

```
df1['is_misc'] = df1['is_misc'].astype(str).astype(int)
df2['is_misc'] = df2['is_misc'].astype(str).astype(int)
```

And then compare again:

```
print(df1 == df2)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Gustav Rasmussen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7445528/gustav-rasmussen) ans will work

i got the same problem but i had a string with decimals (e.g. '5.0') in first dataframe and integer in 2nd dataframe ( e.g. 5)

i solved the follwing way

```
df1['column'] = df1['column'].astype(float).astype(int)

df2['column'] = df2['column'].astype(float).astype(int)
```

and compare

```
df1==df2
```